# Concatenate comma delimited column values are remove duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to concatenate comma delimited column values stored in an oracle table.  I will also need to remove duplicated values when I concatenate the column values.  I'm new to oracle and not sure where to start.  Can someone help me achieve the following in oracle 11g?

```
Table:
rec_id     affiliations
1          P,QE,D
2          EE,ED-D
1          QE,PO-D, D 
2          A,EE

Desired output:
rec_id    affiliations
1         P,QE,D,PO-D
2         EE,ED-D,A,EE
```

Answer (score 2):

The first part of this query parses the input into a separate row for each affiliation; the final select concatenates them into a single list for each rec_id.

```
with parsed as (
  select distinct
         rec_id
        ,ltrim(regexp_substr(','||affiliations,',([^,])+',1,i), ',') k
  from t, (select rownum i from dual connect by level <= 100)
  where regexp_substr(','||affiliations,',([^,])+',1,i) is not null)
select distinct
       rec_id
      ,listagg(k, ',') within group (order by k) over (partition by rec_id) affiliations
from parsed
order by rec_id;
```

Adjust the number (e.g. `100`) to the maximum number of items you'd expect to see in the input.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37b44/4